# MySQL apparently can't tell difference between strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I bumped into this quite weird case:

`select count(*) from shipments where user_id = 1  and pickup_id = 2` returns **2**

`select count(*) from shipments where user_id = 1 and pickup_id = 2 and order_id = 'AAA'` returns **1**

`select count(*) from shipments where user_id = 1 and pickup_id = 2 and order_id <> 'AAA'` returns **0**

What on earth is going on? I'm using MySQL 5.7.17

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, `order_id` is `NULL` in one row.

Instead of `<>`, use:

```
select count(*)
from shipments
where user_id = 1 and pickup_id = 2 and
      (not order_id <=> 'AAA')
```

The `<=>` is the `NULL`-safe equality operator (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)).  MySQL doesn't have a single `NULL`-safe inequality, so just use `NOT` or:

```
(order_id <> 'AAA' or order_id is null)
```

Comment: That's exactly it! `order_id` is `null`

Answer (score 2):

Possibly there is a null value in order_id. <> will not account for that.

`<>` is not not NULL-tolerant. However '`NOT IN`' is. So instead of `<>` use `NOT IN`

```
select count(*) from shipments where user_id = 1 and pickup_id = 2 and order_id NOT IN ('AAA')
```